# Problemas con urllib en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
exec(open("selectorproxy.py").read())
proxy = open("proxys.txt", 'r').readlines()
puerto = open("puertos.txt", 'r').readlines()
consulta = urllib.request.urlopen('https:socks5://'+proxy+':'+puerto+'//www.fotocasa.es/es/')
```

Cuando intento hacer la conexión salta el siguiente error

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

Comment: No puedes concatenar un string y una lista.

Comment: Cómo puedo solucionar este error?

Comment: Depende de que es lo que esperas obtener de los txt. readlines te devuelve una lista con todas las lineas del txt.

Comment: necesito de cada archivo solo una línea y poder hacer la petición con estos datos a fotocasa.es

Comment: Que linea necesitas? La primera?

Comment: si, solamente necesito eso

Comment: En ese caso, puedes usar el método readline. Como el puntero inicia al principio del archivo, te leerá la primera linea. Pero recuerda que readline toma toda la linea incluyendo el salto de linea. Tendrás que quitarselo. Recomiendo usar el método [rstrip](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) de las cadenas. En resumen, recomiendo el siguiente código para obtener la primera linea sin el salto de linea: `elarchivo.readline().rstrip("\n")`. Donde la cadena "\n" representa un salto de linea.

Comment: muchas gracias, funciona